# linux volume change after plugging USB camera or changing playback from a different SW

Tags: pulseaudio, webcam, volume-control

When I plug in a USB camera then the volume levels are changed to some preset values. It also happens sometimes when I start some audio playback from a different SW (e.g. radiotray or mplayer). I don't want this automatic volume changing. I have XUbuntu 14.04 and I suspect PulseAudio but I can't figure out how to disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stream output volume is a feature which allows individual stream properties based on applications.

For **streams** it is controlled by the pulseaudio module `module-stream-restore`, for audio **devices** it is controlled by `module-device-restore`, and for sound **cards** (if multiple) it is `module-card-restore`.

To test whether our issue is resolved we can temporarily unload any of these modules (which should be loaded from our `default.pa`), e.g.:

```
pacmd unload-module module-stream-restore
```

The module will be re-loaded by restarting the pulseaudio sound server with

```
pulseaudio -k
```

If after unloading the issue was resolved we can prevent loading this module by commenting out the line in our `default.pa` (located in `/etc/pulse/`, `~/.pulse/`, or `~/.config/pulse/` like this:

```
#load-module module-stream-restore
```