# ubuntu 17.10 pulseaudio with bluetooth a2dp does not offer playback stream for firefox

Tags: sound, firefox, 17.10, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I've got a bluetooth adapter which works fine as a pulseaudio high fidelity playback (a2dp) device in Ubuntu 17.10. The speaker test works fine in the standard sound settings GUI when I connect to bluetooth using headphones. The problem is that Firefox YouTube videos don't use the bluetooth adapter.. they consistently play over the HDMI speaker.

I installed kmix and it says that Firefox is using a Playback Stream - specifically 'Firefox: AudioStream'.

If I vary the volume of the HDMI audio in the kmix Playback Devices tab, it varies the sound level of the YouTube video playing over the HDMI speaker.

The bluetooth headphone also has a slider at max volume in this tab, but the headphones do not receive any sound from the browser. When the headphone slider volume is changed, a pleasing 'thwop' sound is heard in the headphones.

Is there a way to get Firefox to output to the bluetooth adapter?

thanks!

Comment: Can you switch to the BT sink with **pavucontrol**? If yes then try if [deleting default.pa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201780/how-do-i-debug-issues-with-pulse-audio/202533?s=13|0.0000#202533) helps or, if not try with [unloading `module-stream-restore`](https://askubuntu.com/a/538290/3940) or `module-device-restore` or `module-card-restore`).

Comment: thanks Takkat. I was able to configure the Firefox audio stream to use the bluetooth audio headset using pavucontrol :). If you answer the question i'll approve it.

Comment: @Takkat The OP indicated that your suggestion is an accepted solution but the user did not tag your username at the beginning of the last comment so you probably didn't receive any notification.

Comment: @JamesFremen Hi James! You can address a specific user at the beginning of your comment so that the user will receive notification to respond. Just use the "at-symbol" followed by the username you wish to address as I have done in this comment addressed to you. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesFremen: notice received :) Feel free to self-answer your own question with the exact steps you took to get it working - I am sure other people will benefit from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @Takkat comment, i found the following steps worked with Ubuntu 17.10:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Within pavucontrol it's possible to designate the BT device for output (once it has connected). If a video with sound is playing in a browser, an entry for the browser will appear in the Playback tab. The bluetooth device can then be specified.

This device is both reasonably priced and seems to work well with 17.10. Just saying.. there was a lack of information when i last looked.
https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00E38N7QE/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1